# MVC Ajax.BeginForm - Model valid and data added to dbase but constantly triggering OnFailure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-ajax

I am at the end of my tether with this. I am trying to update a list of Contacts in a page using an Ajax Form in a partial view and I keep hitting this weird error. For the life of me I cannot understand why this is happening since this action is pretty much a clone of another form/action combo in my project and that one works!!

When I submit the form, I've been tracking it with the debugger. The model IsValid and it saves the data to the database successfully. Despite this though, the form is triggering the OnFailure method. Further probing in the Chrome Console reveals that I am getting a 500 Server Error on the action I am calling

[image: The Offending Error]

I cannot understand how this is happening since I am sending the correct model to the Controller Action; the debugger shows it's valid and my form data is being saved in the database after all.

This is the model

```
public class ClientContact
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
    //public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
}
```

This is the controller action I am calling

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult CreateContact([Bind(Include = "Id,ClientId,FirstName,LastName,Position,Email,Telephone")] ClientContact clientContact)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.ClientContacts.Add(clientContact);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return PartialView("AddCanNote", new ClientContact { ClientId = clientContact.ClientId });
        }
        return new EmptyResult();
    }
```

This is my Partial View

```
@model _3KB.Entities.Client_Entities.ClientContact

<div id="clientContactTarget">
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span6">
        @{Html.RenderAction("ContactsForClient", "ClientContacts", new { clientId = Model.ClientId });}
    </div>
    <div class="span6">
        <h5>Add New Contact</h5>
        <hr/>
        @using (Ajax.BeginForm("CreateContact", "ClientContacts", null, new AjaxOptions
        {
            HttpMethod = "POST",
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
            UpdateTargetId = "clientContactTarget",
            OnSuccess = "SuccessContact",
            OnFailure = "FailureContact"
        }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span6">
                    <div class="control-group">
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ClientId)
                        @Html.Label("First Name")
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName)
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="span6">
                    <div class="control-group">
                        @Html.Label("Surname")
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName)
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span4">
                    <div class="control-group">
                        @Html.Label("Position")
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Position)
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="span4">
                    <div class="control-group">
                        @Html.Label("Telephone")
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Telephone)
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="span4">
                    <div class="control-group">
                        @Html.Label("Email")
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email)
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span12">
                    <div class="control-group">
                        <input type="submit" value="Add Contact" class="btn blue"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

And I am calling this in the parent view with

```
@Html.Partial("AddClientContact", new ClientContact {ClientId = Model.Id })
```

I've been looking at this all day now. I thought I'd figure it out but I think I've been looking at it too long.

Has anyone experienced a similar issue to this?

Any suggestions or advice would be welcomed

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your action raising an exception doesn't cause anything done previously in the action to be rolled-back. Since the exception isn't raised until view processing (which is one of the last things to happen in the response-pipeline) everything will be saved and such just fine.

Second, `OnFailure` will be hit if the action returns 500. It doesn't matter that it did all the core stuff it was responsible for (writing to DB, etc.) fine, it's still returning a 500, so it's a failure.

Finally, the exception is pretty explicit. Somewhere, you're passing `ClientContact` to a  view that accepts only `CandidateComment`. A common source of this is loading a partial within another view, and neglecting to explicitly pass a model. For example, let's say you had a view, `Foo.cshtml` that has a model declaration of `CandidateComment`. If you were to do the following in a view whose model is `ClientContact`:

```
@Html.Partial("Foo")
```

You're in fact actually passing the `ClientContact` instance from the main view to that partial, just as if you were to do:

```
@Html.Partial("Foo", Model)
```

Long and short, look at all views that are involved in rendering the view for this action. Find the one that has a model declaration line including `CandidateComment` and then make sure you pass it a `CandidateComment` instance when you call it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Chris. I have extensively searched for this all day today after seeing the error detail in the Chrome Console. My first thought was that I had probably sent the wrong model to the partial view and expected to fix it immediately. However this isn't the case. The two entities are completely unrelated and I have no idea how I've managed to get this so wrong when, it would seem, nothing in the Clients area has any reference to a candidatecomment.

Comment: There's something, somewhere. You might need to throw a wide net at first and then reel it in. Do a solution-wide search for "CandidateComment" (easier if you combine with "Find All", instead of going one by one). Pick out the views that reference it, then do searches for those view names (i.e. If it's `Foo.cshtml` then do a search for `"Foo"` or `Partial("Foo"` if you want to narrow it down some. Notice that that will catch both `Html.Partial` and `Html.RenderPartial`.)